# Проверка целостности файла по SHA1, можно ли доверять

Tags: взлом, цифровая-подпись, sha1

Скачал файл (ISO образ) размером примерно 3.8 Гига, для проверки целостности предлагают использовать контрольную сумму SHA1. На сколько этому алгоритму проверке целостности можно доверять? На сколько сложно внести изменения в образ ISO и потом **подделать** контрольную сумму чтобы она **совпадала** с нужной?

Comment: Эдвард Сноуден, залогинтесь.

Comment: Я не настоящий сварщик, но по-моему сейчас подделка файла зашифрованного sha1 возможна скорее в теории, а практически такая атака неприминима

Comment: @linova настолько, что в iso образе останется разве что какая-то чепуха, которую невозможно будет прочесть. Поэтому контрольные суммы - это не столько защита от враждебных изменений (они становятся бесполезны в тот момент, когда вообще на пороге появляется хеш-функция), сколько контроль целостности - правильно ли файл по сети дошел.